# Python printing messages if there is a handshake or if the handshake fails

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, tls1.2

I have this code and I want to test a couple of sites with old tls protocols to see if they are supported or not. My question is, how can I make it print *"TLS protocol supported"* if my set protocol works and If the site does not support the protocol , how can I make it print *"TLS protocol not supported"*

```
import socket
import ssl



context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_1)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname='www.verisign.com')
ssl_sock.connect(('www.verisign.com', 443))
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ssl.html says: " exception ssl.SSLError

    Raised to signal an error from the underlying SSL implementation (currently provided by the OpenSSL library). This signifies some problem in the higher-level encryption and authentication layer that’s superimposed on the underlying network connection. This error is a subtype of socket.error, which in turn is a subtype of IOError. The error code and message of SSLError instances are provided by the OpenSSL library.". You can connect to various websites listed at https://badssl.com/ to test your client.

Comment: PS: you should not force a specific TLS version, like 1.1 because 1) it means you force yourself into NOT accepting anything better if the server allows it and 2) TLS 1.1 is mostly the forgotten child in the serie, you should try at least TLS 1.2 if you really want to force things. But better not forcing things: any good client TLS stack will connect in such a way to select the highest possible version with the server, hence you get the best security possible and you are future-proof, when new versions come out, like TLS 1.3 recently.

Comment: This is a school project and I'm told to check every single protocol, from the oldest to the newest! @PatrickMevzek